# Actions View not showing what it should - XML OpenErp

Tags: python, xml, view, module, odoo

I got this view

```
<record id="action_certificados_certificados" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="requisicion_id">Certificados</field>
    <field name="res_model">certificados.certificados</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
```

It works perfectly with what i want with my module.py

```
class certificados(osv.osv):

_name = 'certificados.certificados'
_description="Certificados de No Produccion"

_columns = {
            'Registro_Numero' : fields.integer('Registro Numero'),
            'Fecha_de_Emision': fields.date('Fecha de Emision', required=True, select=True),
            'Fecha_de_Solicitud': fields.date('Fecha de Solicitud', required=True, select=True),
            'Fecha_del_Documento': fields.date('Fecha del Documento', required=True, select=True),
            'Vigencia' : fields.integer('Vigencia'), 'cert_ids' : fields.one2many('certificados.line','requisicion_id','Items del Certificado'),
            'descripcion' : fields.text('Descripcion'),
            'notas' : fields.text('Notas'),
            }


class certificados_line(osv.osv):

_name = "certificados.line"
_description="Certificados No Produccion"
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

_columns = {
    'Item' : fields.integer('Item'),
    'Codigo_Arancelario' : fields.integer('Codigo Arancelario'),
    'product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Material'),
    'Descripcion_Arancelaria' : fields.char('Descripcion Arancelaria', size=42, required = True, translate = True), 
    'Especificaciones_Tecnicas' : fields.char('Especificaciones Tecnicas', size=60, required = True, translate = True), 
    'Cantidad' : fields.float('Cantidad'), 'Unidad_de_Medida': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Unidad de Medida'),
    'Precio_Unitario_Declarado' : fields.float('Precio Unitario Declarado'), 'Moneda' : fields.many2one('res.currency', 'Moneda'),
    'Valor_En_Divisas' : fields.float('Valor En Divisas'),
    'requisicion_id' : fields.many2one('certificados.certificados', 'Certificados de No Produccion', ondelete='cascade'),
    'Cantidad_Consumida' : fields.float('Cantidad Consumida'), 'Cantidad_Disponible' : fields.float('Cantidad Disponible'),

}
certificados_line()
```

But it works only when showing the form as desired, but not in the tree view, if i change the 'res_model' to 'certificados.line' then it shows what it should on tree mode, but then it wouldn't load the certificados.certificados form,

```
       <record id="student_certificados_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">certificados.result.form</field>
        <field name="model">certificados.certificados</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Introducir los datos" version="7.0">
                <sheet>
                    <div class="oe_edit_only">
                        <label for="Registro_Numero" class="oe_inline"/>
                    </div>
                    <h1>
                        <field name="Registro_Numero" class="oe_inline"/>
                    </h1>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="Fecha_de_Emision"/>
                            <field name="Fecha_de_Solicitud"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="Fecha_del_Documento"/>
                            <field name="Vigencia"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Productos">
                            <field name="cert_ids">
                                <tree string="Productos">
                                    <field name="product_id"/>
                                    <field name="Codigo_Arancelario"/>
                                    <field name="Descripcion_Arancelaria"/>
                                    <field name="Especificaciones_Tecnicas"/>
                                    <field name="Cantidad"/>
                                    <field name="Precio_Unitario_Declarado"/>
                                    <field name="Valor_En_Divisas"/>
                                    <field name="Cantidad_Consumida"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                            <separator string="Observaciones"/>
                            <field name="descripcion"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
                <div class="oe_chatter">
                    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                </div> 
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

so i don't know what to do, i just need the tree to work properly. Right now it shows me non sense data.

This is the actual 'tree' declaration on my xml:

```
<record id="view_certificados_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">certificados.tree</field>
    <field name="model">certificados.line</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Certificados" >
            <field name="Item" />
            <field name="Codigo_Arancelario" />
            <field name="Descripcion_Arancelaria" />
            <field name="Especificaciones_Tecnicas" />
            <field name="Precio_Unitario_Declarado" />
            <field name="Valor_En_Divisas" />
            <field name="Cantidad_Consumida" />
            <field name="Cantidad_Disponible" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

This shows properly only if i change certificados.certificados in the actions for certificados.line, but THEN it will not work properly on the form. The form shows without sheet, notebook etc...

This is what it shows me in tree mode right now:

[image: ActionsTree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made tree view of object **certificados.line** and form view of object **certificados.certificados**.

You have to change the tree view with this tree view.

```
<record id="view_certificados_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">certificados.tree</field>
    <field name="model">certificados.certificados</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Certificados" >
            <field name="Registro_Numero" />
            <field name="Fecha_de_Emision" />
            <field name="Fecha_de_Solicitud" />
            <field name="Fecha_del_Documento" />
            <field name="Vigencia" />
            <field name="descripcion" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Until now what are you doing is you made form view of object **certificados.certificados** and tree view of **certificados.line**. So why this generate problem.

If you make **action** for object **certificados.certificados** then tree view and form view must be of this object.

Hope you understand

Comment: Thank you again! Yes, you right, now it works, the problem is that my client needs in the tree view, the fields that are contained in certificados.line, is there a possible way to do that?

Comment: @NeoVe, have you solved the problem in this comment above?